# Chrome devtools save changed file path

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I use browsersync and run site on local machine on http://localhost:3000/ — when i change css file (example path: ./static/css/menu.css/from devtools - it saved to root project folder in ./localhost%253a3000/static/css/menu.css

how can i change this path?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you followed the steps in https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/workspaces/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You got [override locals](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides) featured enabled. You need to disabled it, and enable [workspaces](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/devtools-release-notes#workspaces) feature instead. I'm not giving all details because this features are different from chrome version to another. You can use the links to get workspaces working.